# Unsetting values on a multidimentional array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unset

I got a multidimentional array of objetcts wich needs to be "filtered" in some cases. This is the function I wrote:

```
foreach($data["index"] as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match("/EXPRESSION/",$value->property)){
        unset($data["index"][$key]);
    }
}
```

It doesn't returns me any errors, but when the array is var_dumped, the values I thought I've unset are still there.

I found this on another topic:

```
foreach ($this->result['list'] as $key => &$row) {
    if ($this_row_is_boring) {
        unset($this->result['list'][$key]);
    }
}
```

I think the only difference from the one I wrote, is that he calls $this->result when I call $data.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the regular expression makes no match, `unset()` will never be called.

Can you insert a statement to determine if `preg_match()` ever returns true?

```
if(preg_match("/EXPRESSION/",$value->property)){
    unset($data["index"][$key]);
    echo "Match found with \$key: $key\n";
}
```